# Move the legend a little bit higher

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have the following code to draw a coordinate space ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/digeti/6/edit?html,output)), I found that the title/legend of Y axis (ie, `x 10000`) is too close to the Y axis; I want to move it a little bit higher. If I change `yAxis: { title: { y: 0 } }` to `yAxis: { title: { y: -5 } }`, a part of it will be hidden behind. Maybe could we move the whole system to the left bottom a little bit?

Does anyone have a good solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <div id="container" style="height:400px;margin:1.5em 1em;"></div>

  <script>
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo:'container',
      type:'area'
    },
    credits: false,
    legend: false,
    title: { text:"" },
    tooltip: {},
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        color:'rgba(156,156,156,.9)',
        fillColor:'#ffffff',
        lineWidth:1,
        marker: {
          enabled:false,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled:false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      tickmarkPlacement:'on',
      categories:[-1.7, -1.65, -1.6, -1.55, -1.5, -1.45, -1.4, -1.35, -1.3]
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: { text: "x 10000", rotation: 0, y: 0, x:10, margin: -40, align: 'high'},
      tickLength: 10,
      tickWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickmarkPlacement:'on',
      gridLineColor:'#ffffff',
      categories:[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
    },
    series:[{  
        data:[[1,1],[1,3],[2,3],[2,1],[1,1]]
    }]      
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You want to add marginTop here:

```
chart: {
  renderTo:'container',
  type:'area',
  marginTop: 30
},
```

And then you can add negative position to the title. :)
MarginTop basically moves your plotting area down, so you have some empty space at the top.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginTop